# Korean text display issue

Tags: windows, fonts, korean

I am having some problems with Korean text display in Windows Explorer. This is how the file looks when listed in Windows Explorer under different views:

- Thumbnails view

  [image]
- Tiles view

  [image]
- Icons view

  [image]
- List view

  [image]

Notice how I see ??? displayed instead of the Korean text in the Tiles and List view. Why is this happening? How do I fix this display problem?

This is on Windows XP. I have installed East Asian support and Korean Unicode fonts. I have verified that this filename is Korean Unicode text. Everything else Korean works fine in Windows. For example, I can view websites which are completely in Korean Unicode in Firefox/IE correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that the font used for the display in the different list modes is a different font, and that font doesn't have the Korean glyphs.

Comment: Where is the configuration of these fonts in Windows?

Comment: @Ashwin: Start->Control Panel->Display->Appearance
You'll see a window which lets you customize the current theme including colours and fonts.  Maybe try resetting the theme if you've made any changes to it or installed any custom themes.